# How to write a stepping monad?

Tags: functional-programming, monads

Suppose I have some function that will recurs forever, the simplest one I know is:

f x = f x

How can I write a monad that will modify the behaviour of this function, such that it gives me the value of x, and a continuation that will compute the next step, consisting of the value of x at that step and a continuation...

Comment: Are you familiar with the continuation monad?

Comment: Sort of, but can't quite get my head around things. Hence asking for a simple example showing how to transform my recursive function into one that I can step along.

Comment: @user2800708 What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using Standard ML, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could structure this as something like the following (using Haskell for illustrative purposes):

```
data Steps a where
  Done :: a -> Steps a
  ToDo :: b -> (b -> Steps a) -> Steps a
```

with the obvious monad implementation.

However, since `b` is existentially typed in the `ToDo` constructor, you won't be able to do much with these intermediate results. In effect, I don't think this will give you any more information than just the plain old partiality monad of

```
data Partial a = Now a | Later (Partial a)
```

Comment: In fact the partiality monad is what I ended up using - I just didn't know what is was called until now. The only difference is that I made it lazy by putting Later (() -> Partial a), as ML is not lazy like Haskell. A very helpful answer, thank you.